# jquery mobile how to add a bookmark

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a bookmark as normal on my jquery mobile page but it is interpreted as page transition. How to set then a bookmark if using jquery mobile?

```
<a name="Ancla" id="a"></a>    <!--setting bookmark-->

<a href="#Ancla">Ancla</a>     <!--link-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile docs states:

*Since we use the URL hash to preserve Back button behavior, using page anchors to jump down to a position on the page isn't supported by using the traditional anchor link (#foo). Use the silentScroll method to scroll to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event listeners. You can pass in a yPos arguments to scroll to that Y location. For example:*

```
//scroll to Y 300px
$.mobile.silentScroll(300);
```

Here's a new jsFiddle to what you can do instead: http://jsfiddle.net/dmNqj/3/

What I'm doing is using their mobile silentScroll function and finding the top position of the element you want it to go to.

**UPDATE 2:** Since jQMobile's experimental 'scrollView' plugin disables `$.mobile.silentScroll`, Here's a jsFiddle using jQuery's native `scrollTop` function: http://jsfiddle.net/dmNqj/6/

Comment: already tried but same result, jquery triggers page transition

Comment: What are you clicking on as the bookmark?  The first or second link? Technically the second link isn't pointing to anything.  The `#` denotes an ID. You'd want to flop the name and ID in the top anchor tag.

Comment: nop, sorry, first is used to define bookmark, second one is the link to previously set bookmark. Already edited

Comment: not working. For a normal html both solutions are working but problem is that jquery mobile knows it as internal page

Comment: Can you post/JSFiddle some of your code? adding `data-ajax=false` to the bookmark link SHOULD work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CHeAX/12/ also works for me but jsfiddle do not load jquery mobile includes, see loading message at bottom, it appears when some includes loading error. Great tool but not representative for jqmobile :( still detecting page transition to nowhere...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12203/discussion-between-josh-allen-and-jaume)